# SQL View Outer Apply Speed

Tags: sql-server

I am seeing some strange query speed results when using a view with an outer apply, I am doing a distinct count on 2 different columns in the view, 1 is done in less than 0.1 seconds, the other takes 4-6 seconds, is the second count query returned slower because it is part of the outer apply? If so - how could I speed this query up?

The fast distinct count is -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL([ItemType], 'N/A') AS Items FROM vwCustomerItemDetailsFull
```

The slow distinct count is -

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL([CustomerName], 'N/A') AS Items FROM vwCustomerItemDetailsFull
```

The view is -

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
       IT.Name AS ItemType,
       CASE
         WHEN CustomerItemEndDate IS NULL
               OR CustomerItemEndDate > GETDATE() THEN CustomerItems.CustomerName
         ELSE NULL
       END     AS CustomerName,
       CASE
         WHEN CustomerItemEndDate IS NULL
               OR CustomerItemEndDate > GETDATE() THEN CustomerItems.CustomerNumber
         ELSE NULL
       END     AS CustomerNumber,
       CASE
         WHEN CustomerItemEndDate IS NULL
               OR CustomerItemEndDate > GETDATE() THEN CustomerItems.CustomerItemStartDate
         ELSE NULL
       END     AS CustomerItemStartDate,
FROM   tblItems I
       INNER JOIN tblItemTypes IT
         ON I.ItemTypeID = IT.ItemTypeID
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName,
                                 CustomerNumber,
                                 StartDate AS CustomerItemStartDate,
                                 EndDate   AS CustomerItemEndDate
                    FROM   tblCustomerItems CI
                           INNER JOIN tblCustomers C
                             ON C.CustomerID = CI.CustomerID
                    WHERE  CI.ItemID = I.ItemID
                    ORDER  BY EndDate DESC) AS CustomerItems
```

Comment: Quite possibly the `OUTER APPLY` is never executed in the `ItemType` case as it does not affect the result. What do the execution plans look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the execution plan, this speed difference is not strange at all, since it is an outer apply and not a cross apply, and within it you are limiting the results to top 1, it means that your outer apply has no influence on the number of results of the query, or the column `ItemType`.

Therefore when you select from the view and don't use any columns from the outer apply, the optimiser is smart enough to know it doesn't need to execute it. So in essesnce your first query is:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ISNULL([ItemType], 'N/A') AS Items
FROM    (   SELECT  tblItems
            FROM    Items
                    INNER JOIN tblItemTypes IT 
                        ON I.ItemTypeID = IT.ItemTypeID
        ) vw
```

Whereas your second query has to execute the outer apply.

I have previously posted a [longer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17107503/1048425) which could also be helpful.

**EDIT**

If you wanted to change your query to a JOIN it could be rewritten as so:

```
SELECT I.ItemID,
        IT.Name AS ItemType,
        CustomerName,
        CustomerNumber,
        CustomerItemStartDate,
FROM   tblItems I
        INNER JOIN tblItemTypes IT
            ON I.ItemTypeID = IT.ItemTypeID
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  ci.ItemID,
                    CustomerName,
                    CustomerNumber,
                    StartDate AS CustomerItemStartDate,
                    EndDate   AS CustomerItemEndDate,
                    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ci.ItemID ORDER BY EndDate DESC)
            FROM    tblCustomerItems CI
                    INNER JOIN tblCustomers C
                        ON C.CustomerID = CI.CustomerID
        ) AS CustomerItems 
            ON CustomerItems.ItemID = I.ItemID
            AND CustomerItems.rn = 1
            AND CustomerItems.CustomerItemEndDate  < GETDATE();
```

However I don't think this will improve performance much since you said the most costly part is the sort on `EndDate`, and for your first query it will negatively impact performance because the optimiser will no longer optimise out the outer apply.

I expect the best way to improve the performance will be adding indexes, without knowing your data size or distribution I can't accurately guess the exact index you need, if you run the query on it's own showing the actual execution plan SSMS will suggest an index for you which would be better than my best guess.

Comment: According to the execution plan for the slower select - It seems that the sort in the outer apply is causing 96% of the query time..

Comment: And in the faster one does the outer apply appear at all?

Comment: Correct, the outer apply is not applied and the execution plan is a lot simpler.

Comment: Would it be faster to try and implement an outer join with a where clause for active records instead?